Cite PowerPoint Icons
Microsoft PowerPoint provides a wide variety of icons. I want to use them in a graphic, but can't find any usage terms. Do I have to cite them? And if so, how?

The Microsoft site that you linked to says "These icons are free to use and there's no royalty or copyright to worry about". So, from a legal perspective, there is no need to provide any kind of attribution. From an academic perspective, you would generally not need to cite anything either, just like you do not need to provide a citation for the font used to typeset your document.
A possible exception would be if the icons were somehow relevant to the research conducted (for example, an experimental study on how humans percieve different styles of icons), in which case, you should provide a reference to the source of the icons.
